# Uses and examples of monad transformers?

Tags: haskell, monads

I'm going over Monad Transformers and I understand their main role is to provide a monadic container to hold monads, of different types, which provides a common interface from which to manipulate the 'nested' monads within a computation.

I've attempted to implement my own transformer:

```
data CustomTransformer a = CustomTransformer

class TransformerClass m a where
  lift :: m a -> CustomTransformer (m a)

instance TransformerClass Maybe a where
 lift (Just a) = CustomerTransformer (Just a)
```

Going through [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download;jsessionid=7F9022E04C0AE213B74964BA29E2E69D?doi=10.1.1.39.8039&rep=rep1&type=pdf) paper, I understand that this is incorrect. Their example shows:

```
class MonadTrans r where
  lift :: Monad m => m a -> (r m) a
```

This nests the action `a` in the monad transformer `r m`.

I don't understand *how* using a monad transformer aids in dealing with multiple monadic types within a computation? Can anyone provide a simple explanation and example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find it helpful to understand the kinds that are at play here.

Firstly, as you know, a *monad* is a *type constructor* `m :: * -> *` paired with two operations, `return :: a -> m a` and `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`.

```
class Monad (m :: * -> *) where
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
```

The idea of *monad transformers* is that they're a sort of type-level function that turns a monad into another monad. So given that a monad is a single-parameter type constructor `* -> *`, a monad transformer must be a type of kind `(* -> *) -> (* -> *)`, or `(* -> *) -> * -> *` once you remove the parentheses. A monad transformer is a *two-parameter*  type, whose first parameter is a monad and whose second parameter is a value.

More concretely, a monad transformer is a type `t :: (* -> *) -> * -> *`, such that whenever `m` is a monad `t m` is also a monad. We also require that `t m` be a *larger* monad than `m`, in the sense that any action in `m` can be embedded in `t m`.

```
class MonadTrans t where
    transform :: Monad m :- Monad (t m)
    lift :: Monad m => m a -> t m a
```

I'm using [the "entailment" operator `:-`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9/docs/Data-Constraint.html#t::-45-) from [Kmett's `constraints` package](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/constraints-0.9) in the definition of `transform`; `transform` is a proof that `m` being a `Monad` implies that `t m` is a `Monad`. ([The version of `MonadTrans` in `transformers`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-Class.html#t:MonadTrans) omits the `transform` member because when it was written GHC didn't support the `:-` operator.)

Importantly, `t m a` (aka `(t m) a`) means something different than `t (m a)`. The former is a two-parameter type `t` applied to `m` and `a`. The latter is a one-parameter type `t` applied to `m a`.

A very simple - because I'm on my phone - example of what a definition of a monad transformer looks like:

```
newtype IdentityT m a = IdentityT { runIdentityT :: m a }

instance Monad m => Monad (IdentityT m) where
    return = IdentityT . return
    IdentityT m >>= f = IdentityT $ m >>= (runIdentityT . f)

instance MonadTrans IdentityT where
    transform = Sub Dict
    lift = IdentityT
```

Note that `IdentityT` is a two-parameter datatype; the first parameter `m :: * -> *` is a monad and the second parameter `a :: *` is a regular type.

```
ghci> :k IdentityT
IdentityT :: (* -> *) -> * -> *
```

Answer (score 3):

Monads, are any of the polymorphic data types `m a`, that implement the monad operations, `return` and `>>=`, and obey the monad laws.

Some monads have a special form, in that `m` can be written as a polymorphic  `mT m'`, and will be a monad as long as the parameter `m'` is a monad. Monads that we can split like this are monad transformers. The outer monad `mT`, adds a monadic effect to the inner monad. We can nest unlimited amounts of monads, since the inner `m'`, may itself be a monad transformer.

Since Maybe is one of the simplest monads, I'll repost code from [Transformers](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/src/Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe.html#MaybeT).

The definition shows that the monad, `MaybeT m`, is mostly a wrapper around the monad `m`. However, `m` is no longer a "pure" monad, but with a type parameter tainted by the Maybe effect.

```
newtype MaybeT m a = MaybeT { runMaybeT :: m (Maybe a) }
```

Now the definition of the Monad instance.

```
instance (Monad m) => Monad (MaybeT m) where
    return = lift . return
    x >>= f = MaybeT $ do
        v <- runMaybeT x
        case v of
            Nothing -> return Nothing
            Just y  -> runMaybeT (f y)
```

Looking at the bind operation `>>=`, it's important to note that the do notation following the `$` takes place in the `m` monad. The inner monad is recovered via `runMaybeT x`, and the monadic value is bound to `v`, triggering the `m` effect. Then, the `Maybe` state is evaluated, `f` is applied to a value (if existing) and wrapped appropriately.

One source of confusion for me is the terminology for inner and outer monad--and I wouldn't be surprised if I had it backwards. The transformed monad `mT` is actually projecting itself inside the inner monad, `m`.

The question asks about `lift`, which corresponds to the ability to run the inner monad in the pure context of the outer monad. Note that `lift` or MonadTrans doesn't define the transformer, but says that if a monad `(t m)` is a transformer, then you should be able to lift `m a` into a pure `(t m) a`

For my example, the below is a mockup of some program where users 
ask for some resource. The function, `userGetResource` asks for the user's name, then queries that name against some registry, if the name is found, it will attempt to get permission for the user, if permission is given for the user it will return the resource. There are a series of IO actions which may fail with `Nothing`. MaybeT helps write the function so that it is a little more friendly to read and maintain. Note especially the use of `lift` in the `userGetResource` function. Since it will always return a string (baring catastrophe), this function is lifted into the pure `Just` form of MaybeT.

```
import Data.List(find)
import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Control.Monad.Trans.Class(lift)

data User = User { userName :: String, hasCredentials :: Credentials }
type Credentials = Bool
type Token = ()
type UserReg = [User]
data Resource = Resource deriving Show

userGetResource :: IO (Maybe Resource)
userGetResource = runMaybeT $ do
  str <- lift $ do putStrLn "Who are you"
                   getLine
  usr <- MaybeT $ getUser str
  tok <- MaybeT $ getPermission usr
  MaybeT $ getResource tok


getResource :: Token -> IO (Maybe Resource)
getResource _ = return (Just Resource)

userRegistry :: IO UserReg
userRegistry = return [User "Alice" True, User "Bob" False]

lookupUser :: String -> UserReg -> Maybe User
lookupUser name = find ((name==) . userName)

getUser :: String -> IO (Maybe User)
getUser str = do
  reg <- userRegistry
  return $ lookupUser str reg

getPermission :: User -> IO (Maybe Token)
getPermission usr
  | hasCredentials usr = do
     tok <- generateToken
     return (Just tok)
  | otherwise          = return Nothing

generateToken :: IO Token
generateToken = doSomeUsefulIO
  where
    doSomeUsefulIO = return ()
```

And here is the output of several calls to `userGetResource`

Fails, "Sam" not in userReg

```
*MaybeTrans> userGetResource
Who are you
Sam
Nothing
```

Succeeds, "Alice" in registry and has permission.

```
*MaybeTrans> userGetResource 
Who are you
Alice
Just Resource
```

Fails. "Bob" is in registry, but no permission.

```
*MaybeTrans> userGetResource
Who are you
Bob
Nothing
```

Answer (score 1):

Different monads give different "effects" such as state or nondeterminism. But if you want more of these in a monad you need to either implement such a monad from scratch (which would be tedious) or stack the monads somehow. Transformers are there to allow stacking the effects of various monads. Transformers are often obtained by generalisation from a monad that provides the effect you are interested in, extracting the effect while making it possible to plug another monad inside. It is sort of a decoration for other monads that adds your desired state/nondet/... effect to them. Look at hackage at the package `transformers` to see some common [examples](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/transformers-0.5.2.0/docs/Control-Monad-Trans-State-Strict.html#t:StateT).

Transformer captures the effect of the associated monad but leaves room for you to put another monad in, as in the definition of bind (`>>=`) for `StateT`:

```
(>>=) :: StateT s m a -> (a -> StateT s m b) -> StateT s m b
m >>= k = StateT $ \ s -> do
    (a, s') <- runStateT m s
    runStateT (k a) s'
```

the `do` block "runs" in the underlying monad (`m`, the lines are chained via the bind operator `>>=` of `m`), and thus "does its own thing", while `StateT` maintains the state on the side.

This way you can stack more effects, each transformer taking care of one, and get a monad that has all these effects.

```
ExceptT e (StateT s (ListT IO))
```

Here you express the effects of "throwing exception" in a "stateful" and "nondeterministic" computation in the "realworld" environment provided by `IO`. Please take this just as an example, `IO` itself is stateful so I do not deny the example is a bit too much.

Just a note: concrete monads can then often be expressed as transformations of the simplest monad `Identity` which does nothing interesting on its own, just as `State s` is implemented in terms of `StateT s Identity`.

Comment: "Please take this just as an example, `IO` itself is stateful so I do not deny the example is a bit too much" -- I don't think `StateT` over `IO` is excessive. There is nothing wrong with keeping a layer of pure state apart from `IO`, and it tends to be more pleasant than juggling mutable references around.

Comment: You are right, thats why I put it there anyway, it is just a contrived example as I didn't think of real use case